# Заполнение вектора случайными 15 числами от 22 до 23 ( 22< x < 23)

Tags: c++, vector

Код написал вроде бы правильно,но с диапазоном что-то не то,должны выводиться числа от 22.0 до 23.0 например 22.3 , 22.4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<float> Elements;
    for (float i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        float  Elements = (rand() %23 +22);
    cout << Elements;
    cout <<  endl;
}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

надо случайное число от 0 до 1 сформировать, например так:

```
22 + (float)rand() / RAND_MAX
```

если не важна максимальная ступенчатость (которая по сути RAND_MAX задается), то можно можно и так

```
22 + (rand() % 100) / 99.0
```

> Код написал вроде бы правильно

нет, не правильно

```
(rand() %23 +22);
```

будет выводить от `22 + 0` до `22 + 22`

**P.S.**

ну и самое главное - раз пишете на c++ и используете stl, то почему бы не обратить внимание и на библиотеку случайных чисел, которая удобный интерфейс вам предоставляет для вашей задачи

```
#include <random>

std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generator(device());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distr(22.0, 23.0);

for (int n = 0; n < 15; ++n) {
    std::cout << distr(generator) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал исправить свой код вашим выдает такую ошибку(пробовал 2 варианта) 
Ошибка C2679 бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Comment: Прошу прощение,додумался.

Comment: @Olexandr Dzynhar, посмотрите ответ, я его дополнил кодом, который в 21 веке на с++ (начиная с с++11) лучше всего использовать, кроме того сейчас можно подключить не генератор псевдослучайных чисел, а генератор истинно случайных чисел

Comment: Сколько вижу С++, столько и не перестаю поражаться людям, пользующим его. Почему бы за последние 20 лет (время, когда язык уже устоялся), не добавить в стандартную библиотеку что-то вроде `drand()`, простого вызова, который можно **легко использовать** вместо отталкивающего месива кода

Comment: @avp сколько уже лет C, а почему-то вектор до сих пор не добавили в стандартную библиотеку 

Comment: @avp, так вроде же есть в стандартной библиотеке функция, которую легко использовать: `rand()` :)

Comment: @avp, проблема таких простых функций в том, что нет однозначного ответа, как они должны работать. Какой алгоритм использовать для генерации чисел? Что должна возвращать функция? `double`? `int`? `uint_least64_t`? Как инициализировать начальное состояние генератора? Если каждая реализация будет отвечать на эти вопросы на своё усмотрение, то мы получим очередной `rand()`. С другой стороны, имея такой набор заготовок в `<random>`, можно сконструировать генератор случ. числе на своё усмотрение. А если не нравится "месиво кода", то его можно упаковать в свой класс. Это ж C++.

Comment: [C++ damages the brain … – EWD](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/)